# Feeding raw meat to kittens

Tags: cats, health, diet

There is this mommy cat and a young one wandering around our neighborhood. Today I just shredded some beef, cut the remaining in to small chunks and gave it to the kitten. I heated it in the microwave and made it warm enough so that he could digest it properly. He ate about three quarters of it and immediately started shivering (around the tummy area) and made burping-like noises. He kept on eating, but I removed the food and he was so very sad...

Now, after about two hours, the fella looks relaxed. I kept checking up on him every 30 minutes. I don't know his age, but his mom is still with him. Does it mean he is still being breastfed? Can I continue feeding him? I am completely inexperienced when it comes to pets. He is about 15-20 cms long excluding the tail. I did it thinking it would be good for him, but now I feel terrible! There are some unhealthy source of food for both of them all around the area - trash cans, kitchen wastes and so on. Some other neighbors might be feeding them too. If it would help your answer, I could post a picture of the kitty.

Comment: Please see [Can cats safely eat raw meat?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/14/can-cats-safely-eat-raw-meat?rq=1) to see if that answers your question. If not, please update this question to reflect and I'll reopen.

Comment: @JohnCavan Thank you for the notification. I did read that one before posting this, but that was for adult cats, wasn't it? Is it same for both adults and kittens? If that is the case, then there is no need for reopening this.

Comment: If the kitten has reached the stage where it's no longer nursing, then yes. However, as I said in that other question, care is required with meats for human consumption. It's better, if you want to feed feral cats, to use something more nutritionally balanced for felines.

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate as it specifically asks about kittens and they have different nutritional considerations from adult cats. In either case of kittens or cats, feeding them raw meat is a terrible idea for several reasons: salmonella and E. coli as well as a lack of thiamine in the case of fish or vitamin A toxicity in the case of liver. http://pets.webmd.com/cats/ss/slideshow-foods-your-cat-should-never-eat See also: https://www.iams.com/pet-health/kitten-care/10-myths-about-raw-diets-for-kittens---iams

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as the OP is asking about the cat's health