# Is raw pork bad for cats?

Tags: cats, health, diet

I'm wondering if there are some health risk associated with feeding cats with human grade raw pork?

My cat is quite picky about foods. I've tried pork several times and the cat definitely prefers it to dry or wet cat food or even low-grade microwaved fish.

The only downside that I've seen is that the cat's fur smells like pork and a bit sticky after feasting with pork.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can cats safely eat raw meat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/14/can-cats-safely-eat-raw-meat)

Comment: @Sonevol the answer you mentioned is too broad and includes all meats. My question is specific about pork. Also there are contradictory answers there, so I don't know which one to believe.

Comment: Some of the comments are getting of topic, deleted them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three things to take into consideration when feeding raw pork:

#### Trichinellosis

It's not a concern for two reasons:

- Trichinellosis is eradicated in most European countries and in the USA. (In Germany, for example, it's common for humans to eat [raw pork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mett))
- Cats won't show any symptoms, meaning it's not harmful to them. [Source](https://wagwalking.com/cat/condition/trichinellosis)

#### Aujezky's disease also called pseudorabies

It's much less known but much more a concern. It's less know as it's not transmissible to human and much more a concern because it's fatal to cats.  [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorabies)

Fortunately, now domestic pigs are free from it and regularly tested in Europe and the US. Though it's safer to not feed free-range pigs, and don't feed wild boar.

It's important that you check the epidemiology in your country before feeding raw pork.

#### Balanced diet

Finally, pork meat alone isn't a balanced diet. If you want to keep feeding, look for a [prey model diet](https://perfectlyrawsome.com/cats/prey-model-raw-pmr-for-cats/), which is a way to balance a meat-based raw diet.

So if your country is free from Aujezky's disease and you provide a balanced diet you can feed raw pork.

Comment: Thank you for this well referenced and researched answer.

Answer (score 4):

Raw pork meat do  have a risk for trichinosis the risk do vary after where you are located but the risk is not zero anywhere.

It is better to feed other types of meat where the risk is lower,And pork meat do contain an higher amount of fat,Cats do not need to eat fat many cats will refuse to eat it.

So it is best to avoid feeding raw pork to your cat,Raw or under cooked pork is not safe for humans to eat and it is not safe for cats.

No single meat contain all the nutrients a cat need so you need to give other types of food to your cat,So you can be sure it gets a balanced diet with the nutrients it need.

Here is a link for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichinosis